# DI Unity Container resolution error

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

I am trying to fake Enterprise Library `LogWriter` so it doesn't perform any logging when I run unit tests, so it looks like this in simplified version:

```cs
public class MockLogger : ILogger
{
      public MockLogger()
      {
      }

      public void Write(object message)
      {        
      }

      public void Write(object message, string category)
      {     
      }

      public void Write(object message, string category, int eventId)
      { 
      }

      public void Write(object message, string category, int eventId, int priority)
      {
      }

      public void Write(object message, string category, int eventId, int priority,   TraceEventType severity)
      {
      }
}

public class Logger : ILogger
{
      LogWriter writer;
      public Logger()
      {
          writer = (new LogWriterFactory()).Create();

      }

      public Logger(LogWriter logWriter)
      {
          writer = logWriter;
      }

      public void Write(LogEntry logEntry)
      {
          writer.Write(logEntry);
      }

      public void Write(object message)
      {
          writer.Write(message);
      }

      public void Write(object message, string category)
      {
          writer.Write(message, category);
      }

      public void Write(object message, string category, int eventId)
      {
          writer.Write(message, category, eventId);
      }

      public void Write(object message, string category, int eventId, int priority)
      {
          writer.Write(message, category, eventId, priority);
      }

      public void Write(object message, string category, int eventId, int priority,   TraceEventType severity)
      {
          writer.Write(message, category, priority, eventId, severity);
      }

      public bool ShouldLog(LogEntry logEntry)
      {
          return writer.ShouldLog(logEntry);
      }
}
```

Then i am trying to resolve it thru configuration:

```xml
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2012/unity">
<alias alias="ILogger" type="ConsoleApplicationTest.ILogger, ConsoleApplicationTest" />
<namespace name="ConsoleApplicationTest" />
<assembly name="ConsoleApplicationTest" />
<container>
  <register type="ConsoleApplicationTest.ILogger, ConsoleApplicationTest" name="logger" mapTo="ConsoleApplicationTest.Logger, ConsoleApplicationTest">
  </register>
</container>
<container name="Mock">
  <register type="ConsoleApplicationTest.ILogger, ConsoleApplicationTest" name="mockLogger" mapTo="ConsoleApplicationTest.MockLogger, ConsoleApplicationTest">
  </register>
</container>
```

```cs
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.LoadConfiguration();
var logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
```

The error I am getting is the following:

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   "ConsoleApplicationTest.ILogger", name = "(none)". Exception occurred
>   while: while resolving. Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The
>   type ILogger does not have an accessible constructor.

Both classes have a parameterless constructor. What should I do to resolve this error? Using .NET 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have registered your types with the `name="logger"` and `name="mockLogger"` you have created [named registrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660853%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) so you need to pass in the name when calling Resolve:

```cs
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.LoadConfiguration();
var logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>("logger"); // or "mockLogger"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So what should I do so that it doesn't require a name to resolve it then?

Comment: Just remove the `name="logger"` from the config so it will be default ILogger. And anyway because your mock implementation is registered in different container the two implementation won't conflict with each other.

Comment: I removed it so now the error I am geting is this `Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "ConsoleApplicationTest.ILogger", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type IEnumerable`1 does not have an accessible constructor.

Comment: Now this is different problem, which might need a different question... From your sample code I cannot see any `IEnumerable` anywhere. So probably there is something wrong with one of the subdependencies registeration... Unity by dafeault uses the constructor with the most parameter, so in your sample: `public Logger(LogWriter logWriter)` . So have you correctly registered the `LogWriter`?

Comment: Can't see it either that's why surprised. `LogWriter` itself is a static object that comes with Enterprise Library and does not require registration

Comment: If you have a constructor in a container registered type where you have an `LogWriter` then it needs to be registered in the container. No matter from where it should come from. According to the doc LogWritter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.logging.logwriter.logwriter.aspx has quite a few constructor arguments so there is no suprise the Unity cannot create it. If you don't plan to register `LogWriter` then if you delete your second constructor `public Logger(LogWriter logWriter)` it should work...